# if else shorthand solution

Tags: php, if-statement, shorthand

I am not sure if the following validation can be done with if shorthand.

```
//if $error is set, echo $errro or just echo blank string.
(isset($error)) ? echo $error:echo '';
```

I know I got it wrong, Anyone here can help me to correct my code? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Called the ternary operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation if you need more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo isset($error) ? $error : '';
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few good examples in [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (ternary operator). But basically usage is:

```
echo (isset( $error) ? $error : '');
```

It also has a short form, that can be used in case that `$error` is always set but is evaluated as `(bool)false` by default:

```
echo ($error ?: '');
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the middle part of the ternary operator can only be left out in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
echo (isset($error) ? $error : '');
```

The inline if is not well implemented in PHP as far as associativity is concerned; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F) for more info.